# Ext Js Combo Filter by distinct items

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, filter, datastore

I have two requirement to bind the EXT Js combo

-- The first Item in the combo should have the fixed text such as "Unfilterd"

-- After that I need to bind the data store to the above combo.  The datastore has repated columnA values, so how can filter the datastore so that it has distinct rows in a columnA before binding the combo.

Note:

I am using the data store to bind the grid panle aswell, I do not want to create another call to database.  That's the reason why I am looking for a solution to filter the data by Ext Js datastore.

My sample code is as below

```
extManager1.comboFilter = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                  editable: false
                , id: 'BaseTemplate'
                , fieldLabel: 'Base Templates'
                , name: 'BaseTemplate'
                , editable: false
                , store: extManager1.GetTemplateDetails
                , displayField:'FilterBy'
                , valueField: 'value'
                , mode: 'local'
                , boxLabel: 'BaseTemplate'
                , typeAhead: true
                , triggerAction: 'all'
                , forceSelection: true
                , selectOnFocus: true
                , emptyText:'Unfilterd'
                ,listeners:{select:{fn:function(combo, value) { 

                //This code filters the grid panel data by selected combo value
                Ext.getCmp('TemplateGridPanel').store.filter('productdisplayheading', combo.getValue());               

                }}

                }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to create another store object with the contents you need. But there's no need to fetch the data again from the database - you can populate the new store with the data in your `extManager1.GetTemplateDetails` store. Take a look at the [collect method of ExtJS Store](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) - it can be used to fetch distinct values from an existing store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But how can i fectch the distinct value from the earlier

Comment: I am not sure how to use the collect method can you please give an example. I also need to add first item as 'Unfilterd' for the combo, how can I achive this.

Comment: You can use `store.insert(0, [yourUnfilteredRecord])` to add the "Unfiltered" item to the store. And `store.collect('columnA')` returns distinct values from columnA of the store.