# Query JS Ext.data.Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

I am planning to use http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.Store.html to store a table and filter the data... For instance the table sales: Product  |  Branch  |  Quantity |  Earning | ...
Suppose the data for quantity and earning are range of values, such as: less than 100, between 101 and 200, etc. and I use a `ComboBox` for each column to filter the data: Product combobox, Branch combobox,...

My design has a global `Store` to hold the table, and one `Store` per `ComboBox`.
I know I can use the event/listener `Select` in the `ComboBox` to apply the filters. Additional, use the `datachanged` of the global `Store` to set the data in the other stores.

My question is: How to get/select/extract a column from the global Store and applies distinct and sort operations to set the data in each combobox-store???

**Update**

Example http://jsfiddle.net/jQXf7/6/

Comment: `collect` can help to select unique values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614771/ext-js-combo-filter-by-distinct-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out the solution using `collect` method of the store and using `Ext.data.ArrayReader` for the `ComboBox` `Stores`.

- [`Collect`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-collect): Collects unique values for a particular dataIndex from this store.
- [`Ext.data.ArrayReader`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayReader): Data reader class to create an Array of Ext.data.Record objects from an Array.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jQXf7/10/ (simple implementation of one filter at the time)